# Form not POST-in

Tags: php, html, post

Does anybody know why this piece of code is not posting?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="./admin/addImages.php" method='post'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="slika1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input id="slika1" name="slika1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Image URL">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button name='saveForm' type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also have this php code which should get the posted input, but its not working:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
          $img = $_POST['slika1'];
          echo "$img";
      } else {
          echo "nothing posted";
      }
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how can i check that? I mean, the php code is from that file and it echoes "nothing posted", and it works if I change to GET

Comment: Images deals with `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`. What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: add image www url to mysql database (that part of the code is not present here) and it works if using GET, but POST doesn't, well, post

Comment: and you think that by leaving out your MySQL code is not relevant?

Comment: You're not responding to my last comment so I have moved on. I'm not going to wait around like your personal butler. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has a period, not sure if this would cause it not to post, but try without.

`action="/admin/addImages.php"`

Comment: the dot represents working directory for wamp, it's not the problem

Comment: would it not be `../admin/addImages.php` then?

Answer (score 0):

replace $_POST['saveForm'] with $_POST['slika1']

or another alternative can be.
You replace

```
<button name="saveForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add image</button>
```

with

```
<input name="saveForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Image">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to post on same page and its working fine and i got data.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method='post'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="slika1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input id="slika1" name="slika1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Image URL">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button name='saveForm' type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
          $img = $_POST['slika1'];
          echo "$img";
      } else {
          echo "nothing posted";
      }
?>
```

I have entered "www.google.com".

**Output**

```
www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

TESTED **As it is, it should work.** The problem has to be somewhere else. Maybe the image name that you are posting is empty.

Comment: as I said in another comment, with GET it works (and the name is not empty there)...maybe this is a stupid question but since I'm new to PHP and HTML, the html code is being printed inside a php echo in one file (everything is printed correctly and works, except this POST), could that maybe affect what's happening?